# The connection between the length of Fibonacci $p$-step numbers and it's limit values

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

One of the most important generalization of the classical Fibonacci numbers is the Fibonacci $p$-step numbers that is defined as follows

\begin{equation}\label{cp26}
 F_n^{(p)}=F_{n-1}^{(p)}+F_{n-2}^{(p)}+\cdots+F_{n-p}^{(p)}\, .
 \end{equation}

With boundary conditions

$$F_{0}^{(p)}=0\quad ,  \quad F_{1}^{(p)}=0\quad ,\, \cdots\, ,\quad F_{p-2}^{(p)}=0\quad , \quad F_{p-1}^{(p)}=1\, .$$

We can get the limit value of Fibonacci $p$-step numbers by inverse of solution of equation $x^{p+1}-2\, x+1=0$ in 
the interval $(0,1)$. 
  We denote the limit value of Fibonacci $p$-step numbers with $\alpha_p$. In fact, $\alpha_p$ is defined in the following form 
  $$
\alpha_p=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}}\quad \frac{F^{(p)}_{n+1}}{F^{(p)}_{n}}~.
  $$

We denote the length of $ F_n^{(p)}$ number with $L_n^{(p)}$. For example,  $ F_{10}^{(2)}=55$ therefore $L_{10}^{(2)}=2$. 
  With simulation, I found the following connection between the length of Fibonacci $p$-step numbers and it's limit values
$$
\mid \frac{F^{(p)}_{n+1}}{F^{(p)}_{n}}-\alpha_p\mid \, \approx \,  10^{-{\displaystyle{L_n^{(p)}(\frac{p}{p-1})}}}~.
$$
I make some examples to clarify what i mean. For $p=2$, the Fibonacci $2$-step number is the classical Fibonacci number. 
The limit value of the Fibonacci $2$-step number is inverse of solution of equation $x^3-2\, x+1=0$ in 
the interval $(0,1)$.
so, for $p=2$, the limit value is

\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha_2= \frac{1}{0.61803398874989484820458683436563811772030917980580}& &  \\
& & \\
= 1.6180339887498948482045868343656381177203091798058~.& &
\end{eqnarray}

The length of $F_{72}^{(2)}$ and $ F_{73}^{(2)}$ are $15$. With calculation, we have the following relation

$$
\mid \frac{F^{(2)}_{73}}{F^{(2)}_{72}}-\alpha_2\mid=
\mid \frac{ 806515533049393}{ 498454011879264}-\alpha_2\mid
 \, \approx \,  10^{-30}~.
$$
For $p=3$, the Fibonacci $3$-step number is called Tribonacci number. 
The limit value of the Fibonacci $3$-step number is  inverse of solution of equation $x^4-2\, x+1=0$ in 
the interval $(0,1)$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha_3= &1.8392867552141611325518525646532866004241787460975 & \\
& 92246778758639404203222081966425738435419428307014& ~.
\end{eqnarray}

The length of $F_{113}^{(3)}$ and $ F_{114}^{(3)}$ are $30$. With calculation, we have the following relation

$$
\mid \frac{F^{(3)}_{114}}{F^{(3)}_{113}}-\alpha_3\mid=
\mid \frac{270409000010299937423541789777}{ 147018402238651639664609196920}-\alpha_3\mid
 \, \approx \,  10^{-45}~.
$$ 
Is there a analytical method that we can proof the mentioned formula.  I would greatly appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: Shouldn't this be the dominant eigenvalue of the matrix associated to the linear recurrence problem?

Comment: Is it possible to explain more, I can not understand what you mean!

Comment: I believe the matrix would be $m_{1,j}=1$ for all $j$, $m_{i,i-1}=1$ for $2\leq i \leq p$, else $m_{i,j}=0$. If you check what this matrix does to the vector $(F^{(p)}_{n+p},\ldots,F^{(p)}_{n})$ you'll see why this encodes the recurrence relation.

Comment: you mean companion matrix. Maybe you right. I did not check.

Comment: @DanRust please see the following link  http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/10-3/ivie-a.pdf